# Access to quantities other than parameter values in in StepMonitor for NonlinearModelFit?

Tags: nonlinear, monitoring

`NonlinearModelFit` obviously does a lot of internal calculations at each step, including determining the `Response` (the value of the fitting function for the current values of the parameters evaluated at the x-values from the data) and the `FitResiduals`. Yet within `StepMonitor`, I only see how to access the current values of the variable parameters. Is there a way within `StepMonitor` for `NonlinearModelFit` to access these other calculated quantities so that I don't have to REcalculate them to display them as the fit progresses?

Comment: I'm not sure that your hypotheses are true. I would expect it to set up a minimization problem and hand it off to a solver. It might only compute the value of the objective function to be minimized. That said, I don't know how to access the objective function's value (if I'm right).

Comment: That is a fair point. But since the objective function for a normal least-squares problem is the sum of the squared residuals, it seems at least *plausible* that the residuals get calculated.